# How to present a timeseries from start and stop times of processes in grafana from mysql?

Tags: mysql, time-series, grafana

I have a table of processes. Each process is unique. Each process starts and stops. Each process execution takes some memory.

```
select starttime, endtime, name, memory from processes;
```

`name` is a unique string, `memory` is an int, `starttime` and `endtime` are `TIMESTAMP` columns.

I would want to draw a time series in Grafana of how much memory was cumulatively used at each time interval in the last 2 days.

So for example, at 01:00:00 there was 0 memory used, at 01:00:05 some process started using 10G memory, at 01:00:10 another process started with 10G of memory, so sum is 20G. Then the processes stop, decreasing the sum of memory used at a time. I want the draw the sum of memory used in time.

Ideally this would be a stacked time graph like this https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2469783/31598440-0225e702-b24e-11e7-8124-3a6bb1f80dee.png but rectangular, as processes use constant amount of memory during lifetime. But I would be happy with just a timeseries.

I tried various `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime) as time, memory as value from processes where $__timeFilter(starttime) AND $__timeFilter(endtime)` and reading https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/ https://community.grafana.com/t/start-time-and-end-time-column-for-graph-or-time-series/44629 https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/ , but I do not understand how to convert start<->end time ranges to a timeseries with points `__interval` apart. How do I do that?

As I understand, I would want to do in pseudocode `for time in $__range; do select time, sum(memory) from processes where time bewteen starttime and endtime; done` but I have no idea how to do that in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the task:

```
-- test table
CREATE TABLE processes (
  starttime TIMESTAMP,
  endtime TIMESTAMP,
  name VARCHAR(64),
  memory INT
  );

-- date range
SET @start := '2023-01-15';
SET @end := '2023-06-15';

-- test data
INSERT INTO processes VALUES 
('2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', 'process 1', 1), -- partially
('2023-03-01', '2023-04-01', 'process 1', 2), -- completely
('2023-05-01', '2023-06-01', 'process 1', 3), -- completely
('2023-07-01', '2023-08-01', 'process 1', 4), -- out of
('2023-01-01', '2023-03-01', 'process 2', 5), -- partially
('2023-05-01', '2023-07-01', 'process 2', 6), -- partially
('2023-03-01', '2023-06-01', 'process 3', 7), -- completely
('2023-08-01', '2023-09-01', 'process 3', 8), -- out of
('2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', 'process 4', 9); -- out of
SELECT * FROM processes;
```

| starttime | endtime | name | memory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | process 1 | 1 |
| 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | process 1 | 2 |
| 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | process 1 | 3 |
| 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00 | process 1 | 4 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | process 2 | 5 |
| 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | process 2 | 6 |
| 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | process 3 | 7 |
| 2023-08-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | process 3 | 8 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | process 4 | 9 |

```
-- the rows which are overlapped with the range
SELECT *
FROM processes
WHERE starttime <= @end
  AND @start <= endtime;
```

| starttime | endtime | name | memory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | process 1 | 1 |
| 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | process 1 | 2 |
| 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | process 1 | 3 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | process 2 | 5 |
| 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | process 2 | 6 |
| 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | process 3 | 7 |

```
-- calculate the part to be counted
SELECT GREATEST(starttime, @start) starttime,
       LEAST(endtime, @end) endtime,
       name,
       memory * TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, GREATEST(starttime, @start), LEAST(endtime, @end)) / TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, starttime, endtime) memory
  -- excess columns, for debug purposes
  , memory original_memory
  , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, starttime, endtime) original_days
  , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, GREATEST(starttime, @start), LEAST(endtime, @end)) counted_days
FROM processes
WHERE starttime <= @end
  AND @start <= endtime;
```

| starttime | endtime | name | memory | original_memory | original_days | counted_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-15 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00.000000 | process 1 | 0.5484 | 1 | 31 | 17 |
| 2023-03-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000000 | process 1 | 2.0000 | 2 | 31 | 31 |
| 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00.000000 | process 1 | 3.0000 | 3 | 31 | 31 |
| 2023-01-15 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00.000000 | process 2 | 3.8136 | 5 | 59 | 45 |
| 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-06-15 00:00:00.000000 | process 2 | 4.4262 | 6 | 61 | 45 |
| 2023-03-01 00:00:00.000000 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00.000000 | process 3 | 7.0000 | 7 | 92 | 92 |

```
-- aggregate and get needed output
SELECT name, 
       SUM(memory * TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, GREATEST(starttime, @start), LEAST(endtime, @end)) / TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, starttime, endtime)) total_memory
FROM processes
WHERE starttime <= @end
  AND @start <= endtime
GROUP BY name;
```

| name | total_memory |
| --- | --- |
| process 1 | 5.5484 |
| process 2 | 8.2398 |
| process 3 | 7.0000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5caphnR5)

If you do not need in partial counting then remove according expressions.

If you need in all processes, even when they do not have any overlapped row in the specified range then gather the processes list with according subquery or from another table and LEFT JOIN this query to it.

Also it is possible that your logic needs in not soft but hard unequiation for one or both overlapping conditions.